# sizeof operator giving error

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("\nsize of int : %d", sizeof int);
return 0;
}
```

is returning error

```
error: expected expression before ‘int’
```

while compiling with C 
and

```
expected primary-expression before ‘int’
```

while compiling with C++, but the following codes works just fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int b;
printf("\nsize of int : %d", sizeof b);
;
return 0;
}
```

Why is it so? What is the difference in both the cases?

Comment: I know it works with a (). I dont understand why it does not work without one.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it doesn't get much better than "because the standard says so", unfortunately. For example, C99 lists `sizeof unary-expression` and `sizeof ( type-name )`.

Comment: [6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why sizeof int is wrong, while sizeof(int) is right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120473/why-sizeof-int-is-wrong-while-sizeofint-is-right)

Answer (score 12):

`sizeof` needs parentheses when used with a type. They're optional with an expression.

Your code would then become:

```
printf("\nsize of int : %zu", sizeof(int));
```

Thanks to @Grijesh, I've also used the right format specifier for `size_t`. If this format specifier causes problems (likely related to Windows), the next best would probably be `%lu`.

Comment: Additionally, correct format string is `%zu` to print `size_t`.

Comment: @chris then also mention that in microsoft compiler where `%uz` not available use `%lu`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Eh, good point. GCC has also complained about it in the past for me just because I had the Microsoft CRT, even though GCC supports %zu.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `brackets()`. When you are using `sizeof` with a type you need brackets. Try this:

```
printf("\nsize of int : %zu", sizeof(int));
```

You may also use the format specifier `%lu` when `%zu` is not available in microsoft compilers.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator is used to determine the amount of space a designated datatype would occupy in memory. To use sizeof, the keyword "sizeof" is followed by a type name or an expression (which may be merely a variable name). **If a type name is used, it must always be enclosed in parentheses**, **whereas expressions can be specified with or without parentheses**.

```
char c;

printf("%zu,%zu\n", sizeof c, sizeof (int));
```