# Do I need to put sizeof after array length in malloc?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, sizeof

My professor told me that the following code is incorrect:

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof *array * length);
```

And that it should instead be:

```
int *array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
```

He said that you're supposed to encase the type between brackets for `sizeof`, and that length **must** come before the `sizeof` operator. He said that I can use `*array` instead of `int`, but that he preferred the latter.

My biggest question is why is it that length must come before size when calling `malloc`, but also why it's preferrable to use the pointer type instead of the pointer itself with `sizeof`.

He also mentioned that casting (i.e. `(int*)`) is desirable, but I'm not sure why it is necessary.

Comment: Amazing how often teachers conflate their personal preferences with what's "correct". The first form is more robust. Your prof also is wrong on the casting bit. Seems they are using a C++ compiler to compile C code, and are unaware of the subtleties in your original **correct** code.

Comment: Have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/817643). You can try showing it to your profs, but I doubt the commutative experience of thousands of developers will sway someone in academia whose already made up their mind. You may have to do what your prof says to gain points, but don't forget what you learn here for when you are no longer under the professor's shackles.

Comment: See also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13120473/10871073) about when you *need* to use brackets around the operand of `sizeof`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are valid, but many veteran programmers will prefer the way you did it.

The advantage of using `sizeof *array` as opposed to `sizeof(int)` is that if you happen to change the type of `array` then you don't need to change how you do the allocation.

There's also no technical reason to multiply by `length` first instead of the element size.  If anything, when looking at a call to `malloc` the first thing you want to know is how many "things" you're allocating, so from a readability standpoint putting the length first might make more sense.  On the other hand, because the result of the `sizeof` operator is unsigned, putting it first guarantees that the math is done with unsigned types if you have multiple array dimensions.

You also *don't* want to cast the return value of `malloc` as that can mask other errors in your code, specifically a missing `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: I recall it being mentioned somewhere that for a multi-dimensional array being allocated like this, it's best to do `sizeof *array * row_len * col_len` - that way the math is always done in unsigned integers (size_t), and overflow is less of a concern.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ah, good point!

Answer (score 2):

`int *array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));` poses another problem when `length` is the product of `int` multiplication.

Consider

```
  int *alloc_array(int rows, int col) {
    int *array = malloc(rows * col * sizeof *array);  // Overflow more likely
    return array;
  }
```

versus

```
  int *array = malloc(sizeof *array * rows * col); // Better
```

In the first, `rows * col` is `int` math and overflows (UB) if the product exceeds `INT_MAX`.

In the 2nd, multiplication is done using `size_t` math.  Overflow occurs when  product exceeds `SIZE_MAX`.

`SIZE_MAX` is often twice are great as `INT_MAX`  Sometimes 8,000,000,000 times larger than `INT_MAX`.

**Lead your multiplication with the wider type.**

---

```
// Use this in the stuck in the 90s prof's class.
int *array = (int *) malloc(length * sizeof(int));

// Otherwise, use
int *array = malloc(sizeof *array * length);
```

Realize that with C, from time-to-time, you will be obliged to code to some arcane standards. (IMO, often not for technical reasons.)   All languages have this issue.  C simply has a longer history.

---

Just noticed [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71503573/2410359) already covered some of this this.

Comment: On a 64-bit Linux machine with `x86_64` CPU, `SIZE_MAX = 2^64-1` (huge number with 20 digits) and `INT_MAX = 2^32 - 1` (slightly more than 2 billions).

Comment: @DmitryKabanov,  `INT_MAX = 2^32 - 1` (which is about 4 billion) is doubtful.  Perhaps you meant  `INT_MAX = 2^31 - 1`?

Comment: yeah, you're right, thank you. I did it wrong, it is a signed type. I actually wrote a small program before posting the above comment, and I did it wrong by computing `INT_MAX` myself via `((int) pow(2, 32) - 1`, which gives the same result as `(int) pow(2, 31) - 1` (this is wrong as it should be `(size_t) pow(2, 31) - 1`). So, yes, `INT_MAX = 2^31` (slightly more than 2 billions).

Comment: @DmitryKabanov Note that `(int) pow(2, 31)` is UB "If the value of the integral part (of the double) cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined."  Mixing FP math and integer math is wrought with pitfalls.

Comment: @DmitryKabanov Broadly speaking, the positive range of `int` and `size_t` are not _defined_ to be a subset of the other although `INT_MAX <= SIZE_MAX` is very common.  For highly portable code, care it needed.

Comment: It is amazing that with all these non-fixed conditions somehow so many programs run and do not crash every second ️

Comment: @DmitryKabanov OTOH sometimes a simply floating point error is [expensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5#Notable_launches), even if rare.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I've read about this case.

Answer (score 1):

The sizeof operator is defined the following way

```
sizeof unary-expression
```

So this line

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof *array * length);
```

is equivalent to

```
int *array = malloc( ( sizeof *array ) * length);
```

But the original line though it is correct is less clear. So the preferable way to write this line is

```
int *array = malloc( length * sizeof *array );
```

or even better

```
int *array = malloc( length * sizeof( *array ) );
```

You may write also like

```
int *array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
```

but if the type of the elements of the dynamically allocated array will be changed then you need to make changes in two places like for example

```
long *array = malloc(length * sizeof(long));
^^^^                                 ^^^^
```

If you will forget to change the type in the sizeof expression then there can be a bug that will be difficult to find in a big project.

In this line

```
int *array = malloc( length * sizeof( *array ) );
```

you need make a change only in one place

```
long *array = malloc( length * sizeof( *array ) );
^^^^
```

So this declaration is less error prone.

Comment: Why is it more clear to write `length` before `sizeof`?

Comment: @LucasAquinodeAssis Because at the first glance it can look like sizeof (*array * length) or even like a multiplication of three variables.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with the first one is this (I changed from 'array' to a name that doesnt carry such obvious connotations)

```
int *twoodle = malloc(sizeof *twoodle * length);

int *twoodle = malloc(sizeof *twoodle);
```

Both are valid, will compile, but only one is correct. And its impossible to tell just by looking at it

I know that the other format has the same problem *but* people think (it was stated above ) "So this declaration is less error prone.". But you can still make errors here too

Point is , make sure your mallocs are correct (duh)

Comment: It could be better when you are more explicit. "Both are valid, will compile, but only one is correct." Which one? People usually skim on the Internet, not try to decrypt.